# how to check whether it is a Galois extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\alpha$ be the root of $X^3-180$ in $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ and let $L$ be the splitting field of $X^3-180$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I've got to check out wether $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is normal and wether $L$ is a Galois extension over  $\mathbb{Q}$.

Well, the polynomial is irreducible by  Eisenstein and $L$ is a  Galois extension as Char $(\mathbb{Q})=0$. I just don't know how to check out whether it is normal. In this case, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has to include $^3\sqrt 180$, which isn't in $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Splitting field is always Galois in characteristic 0 (since it is always normal from its definition, and it is separable since it is in char 0)
$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain Galois conjugate of other roots.  Eg if $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{180}$ then it does not contain complex roots; other cases need more complicated arguments but still it can be done.

Comment: Presumably you mean "Let $\alpha$ be a root of..." since there are actually two complex conjugate roots that are not real.

Comment: Remember that if $F/K$ is a normal extension then **every** irreducible polynomial from $K[x]$ that has at least one of its roots in $F$ must have all of its roots in $F$. Apply what you already observed about the roots of $x^3-180$ with this in mind.